# If statement with code on same block in haml, RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have this Haml view:

```
!!! strict
 %html{:xmlns => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}
   %head
     %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=utf-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}
     %title
       Lighty | #{@page_title || "Home"}
   %body
     #popup Login here
     #fade
     #wrapper
       #container
         #header
           %a#logo{:href => "/"}
         #menu
           %ul#main
             %li#lighty
               %a{:href => "/"} Lighty
                 %ul
                    %li
                       %a Link here
             %li#community
               %a{:href => "/community"} Community
        #content
```

And I would like to add an if on line #16 to check if it is the currently visited page and add the class "active" to the `li` if it returns true.

How do I write that if statement there and is there any easier way to do this?

My plan now is to use a variable like `@current_page` and test if `@current_page == "community"` and add a class if it returns true.

Am I thinking wrong? Is there any easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly suggest creating a helper method called `visited_class` or something similar since it should have access to the current controller/action. Then, you can write all of the code's logic inside of the helper method. This keeps your views drastically cleaner.

You can place this in many places, but since I have so few helpers, I usually just drop it in ApplicationHelper:

```
def ApplicationHelper

  def visited_class(controller, action)
    if params[:controller] == controller && params[:action] == action
      return " active"
    else
      return ""
    end
  end

end
```

Then, in your view/HAML file, simply call `visited_class` and pass in the controller/action that you want to check. You might also be able to use a URL parameter and piece it together from the `request.request_uri`, but that might be a bit more tedious.

Comment: Glad to help! If it works out for you, could you please accept my answer so that others know this question is resolved? Thanks and happy coding :-)

Comment: havent got it to work because i don't know how to put the function in haml, i only get errors :(

Comment: Check out http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/#M000016 about half way down the page. You need to add an equals sign like this `=link_to('Lighty', '/', :class => visited_class(<<your controller here>>, <<your action here>>))` to output ruby code. A dash (-) will run ruby code without outputting it.

Comment: but i want the class added to the li

Comment: Ah, my apologies. See @KandadaBoggu's answer above. It is a bit more straightforward than my approach (I actually have never worked with HAML, so I was just going based off of the documentation that I briefly read).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer and don't worry, im happy to get the function :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the `visited_class` method suggested by `Topher` to the `app\helpers\application_helpers.rb` file. To add a class to the `li` element, change your HAML as follows:

```
%li#lighty{:class => "#{visited_class('pages', 'show')}"}
  %a{:href => "/"} Lighty
    %ul
      %li
        %a Link here
```